# Pulling info from Facebook into Civi

Tags: drupal, social-media, facebook

I am working with an organization with a Drupal-based Civi instance that would like to have their people (members, event registrants, etc) sign into their Civi with Facebook and allow Civi to pull in specific information that they have entered on FB (e.g., email address, location, etc).

I know there are extensions to do this in Drupal (e.g., https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_facebook). Has anyone used this functionality to then get the info into Civi from Drupal? Does anyone have advice about the feasibility of such a project?

Comment: I know Michael McAndrew has done some stuff integrating Facebook and CiviCRM. I will bring this post to his attention.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a particularly good answer to your question, but since Erik asked :)

I've worked on [a chatbot app](https://docs.civicrm.org/chatbot/en/latest/) that can be used to integrate between Facebook and CiviCRM. Chatbot interacts via the messenger platform and pulls in their first name, last name and picture (which is what the messenger app allows). You can then use it it to further populate fields via a chat interface, e.g. you could ask the question "What city do you live in?" and put the answer in the city address field. But that doesn't sound like what you want to do though.

The Drupal module you reference looks like a good start. If you were able to get the info you needed into Drupal that would be a good proof of concept and would probably be a worthwhile first step if you haven't done it already since there is point going down this road if Facebook is not willing to let you have the information that you require.

I suspect getting the info from their into CiviCRM will require some custom coding, unless there is an integration between Drupal user profiles and CiviCRM that I am not aware of.

Hopefully that is of some use - sorry I can't be of more help at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, Micheal, this is super helpful! I don't think this org has the capacity for the custom work that seems needed. Which is really what I needed to determine. I think it's worth me thinking about whether a coordinated effort with several orgs or an MIH is something to pursue. I really appreciate your help and @ErikH-CiviCooP for calling it to your attention.

Comment: you might want to check if civicrm_entity could be used to add the fields to the user entity in such a way that they just therefore use the civicrm database and hence would provide the integration. maybe worth asking at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/civicrm-entity - oh alright, i just did